# How to remove spatial autocorrelation in my ordinal regression data

Tags: regression, bootstrap, ordinal-data

I am trying to deal with complete separation and spatial autocorrelation in an ordinal regression.

The study design:
We flew two transect lines in a helicopter along a 600 km stretch. Transects were separated by 1 km. We recorded vehicle tracks (4 categories, from none to high) and tracks of species A (4 categories, none to high). I am only concerned about the response of species A to vehicles *along the transects*. My expectation is that where there are many vehicle tracks, tracks of species A will not be as common and visa versa. During the flights and on the transect lines, I recorded data every 8 km. However, both species "A" and the vehicles could easily travel more than 8 km in a day along these transects (but could also go on and off transects), so I am concerned about spatial autocorrelation.

I have complete separation in my dataset (not all category combinations have data; for example, species A low category and vehicles medium category have no observations).

I've looked at [Ben Bolker's helpful page](http://rpubs.com/bbolker/glmmchapter) with GLMM worked examples, and I'm using the R package "blme" with function bglmer to model my data since this is supposed to help deal with the complete separation...

```
model <- bglmer(A ~ Vehicles, (1|transect), data = tracks)
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to use a bootstrapping method to remove the spatial autocorrelation I know is present in my data? Or have any suggestions as to how else I could do this? Further, how can I compute a chi-square statistic after using bglmer to help me determine if the model is appropriate?

Shown below is a picture representing what the transects look like and what data are available for each row in the data.frame. As an aside I also have lats and longs for each point (this could come in handy in a spatial autocorrelation test...)

```
head(tracks)

  ID transect Vehicle  A
1  1      1   none    none
2  2      1   >10     none
3  3      1   none    1-10
4  1      2   none    1-10
5  2      2   none    1-10
6  3      2   none    1-10
```

[image: Image of transects]

Comment: You may have more important issues to deal with first. Usually with transect sampling you will need to account for the fact that detectability wanes with distance from the transect.  Your assumptions about that detectability will likely have a stronger effect on the results than any other consideration, such as spatial correlation.  Many of your questions cannot be answered at all, though, because you haven't explained what you are attempting to do with these data.  Describing them? Testing hypotheses? Making predictions? Developing theories? Something else?

Comment: Hi @whuber, thanks for your comments. I've added more detail to my question.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your data?

Comment: Yes, edited the above. I can make up some data, too, if that's helpful...